# C# Linq slower than PHP? Solving riddle #236A

Tags: c#, php, linq

I'm training with solving Olympic IT-riddles on one site.

I have provided two solutions:

```
 - C#
```

> http://ideone.com/exF1HJ

```
 - PHP
```

> http://ideone.com/WbaPHY

I was confused when online judgment showed , that PHP version was faster!!!
Why?

C#: 109 ms 3000 Kb

PHP: 45 ms 0 Kb

How could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C# version creates three arrays that you don't seem to need. You could replace it with:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int charCount = input.Distinct().Count();
if(charCount % 2 == 0) ...
```

The following is probably quicker still:

```
int charCount = new HashSet<char>(input).Count;
```

Answer (score 5):

Given the programs given, the execution time of the important bit of the program - finding the unique characters - would definitely *not* take 109ms. It sounds like whatever "online judgement" is involved is measuring total execution time including process startup, JITting in the case of .NET, etc.

It's a bit like asking which car gets out of a garage faster, and thinking that represents the speed of the car.

Now it's entirely possible that PHP's `array_unique` function really *is* very fast, possibly faster than LINQ... but basically you can't get any useful information out of the benchmark results. You should be looking for benchmarks which execute for seconds rather than milliseconds, and which *don't* include startup/warm-up time, unless that's what you're particularly interested in.

Comment: Indeed, the "0kB" aspect is fairly impressive too!